# How to implement regex for userID field?

Tags: android, regex

I have one userID edittext field, here I am allowing `alphabets and numbers and '.' and '_' and '@' special characters`. But how to restrict only `'.' and '_' and '@'` in edittext field? I want to restrict like this:

1. After text only I want to allow those special characters.
2. Only one time I want to allow those spl characters(don't allow two times like @@,..,__ like this)
3. end of the userID no spl characters.
4. test.new_bike sample example for valid.
5. test..new__bike,........,______,@@@@@@ like words I won't allow.

please help me,this is my regex

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9]+\\s{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([A-Za-z0-9._]+))$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9]+[\\.\\@\\_]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9]+[\\.\\@\\_]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9]+[\\.\\@\\_]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9]+$"
```

Comment: It is nice to see. Good luck !  ))